# how to plot the ROC curve in Ant colony optimization ( Basic Ant miner)

Tags: pandas, roc, ant-colony

I am using a Basic Ant miner( Ant colony optimization algorithm). I want to find the F-score and ROC and Auc score. In the Ant miner code, I have found the value of false positive rate and true positive rate and apply the function but not getting a result. Here is the code.

```
[fpr = false_pos / (false_pos + true_neg)
tpr = true_pos / (true_pos + false_neg)


 def plot_roc_curve(fpr,tpr):
     plt.plot(fpr,tpr, color='red', label='ROC')
     plt.plot(\[0, 1\], \[0, 1\], color='darkblue', linestyle='--')
      plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
      plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
      plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve')
      plt.legend()
      plt.show()
plot_roc_curve(fpr,tpr)][1]
```

Comment: Please, provide full code. Thanks.

Comment: @ sentence, I have mailed you complete code and dataset. you can check it.

Comment: @ sentence Where is your code suggest me the solution for it?